# NodeJS default parameter when last parameter is the callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a function like this one (simplified) :

```
doSmthg (name, age, callback) {
  callback(name, age);
}
```

I'd like to have a default value for age if it's not provided.

I know I could do `doSmthg(name, callback, age=42) {...}` in ES6 but I've been told callback should always be the last parameter as it make the call to the function more readable.

For now the solution I found is to do the following :

```
doSmthg (name, age, callback) {
  if (arguments.length === 2) {
    age = 42;
    callback = age;
  }
}
```

But I find this solution hard to read.

Is this the good solution ? Is there a better one ?

Comment: Is using promises an option?

Comment: @robertklep I never used promises in this project. If it leads to a very "cool" solution I could concider using promises but I'd rather not

Comment: Your function declaration would look like this: `doSmthg(name, age = 42)` (since you don't need to pass a callback anymore).

Comment: @robertklep I'll take a look at this. Thank you :)

Comment: I would definitely suggest using promises.. they are first-class language constructs in ES6 and compose significantly better than callbacks. In nearly every library that has callbacks for me ends up having an "invisible" dependency on `bluebird` because I have to promisify everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this kind of situation you can use something like this:

```
function doSmthg(name, age, callback) {
  if (typeof age === 'function') {
    callback = age;
    age = DEFAULT_VALUE;
  }
  //continue
}
```

Or you can use a Hash of options, that i think it's better because makes the code more readable, depending of the number of parameters:

```
function doSmthg(options, callback) {
  var name = options.name;
  var age = options.age || DEFAULT_VALUE;
  //continue
}

doSmthg({ name: 'batman' }, function() {});
```

Also you can use the [underscore `#extend` function](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) to merge the options with the default values.

Comment: Note that if you're using ES6 (OP appears to be) you can replace your options object with a destructuring assignment. This doesn't change the caller's perspective but from the callee's perspective it's much more readable. `doSmthg({name, age = DEFAULT_VALUE}, callback)`.

Answer (score 8):

If you have access to spread operator:

```
function foo(...args) {
  const callback = args.pop();
  const [name, age = 42] = args;
  // ...  
}
```

But I think it's time to use promises in NodeJS as well.

```
function foo(name, age = 42) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({name, age}), 1000);
  });
}
//...
foo('Sándor').then(x => console.log(x)); // { name:"Sándor", age:42 }
```

Using ES6 promises you can get rid of the so called "callback pyramid", and makes it possible to use your function with ES7 `async-await` keywords. The future is here!

Answer (score 3):

#### Code

```
function foo(args, callback){
    parsed = {name:"John Doe",age:12};      //default values
    for(a in args) parsed[a] = args[a];

    //Arguments are accessible like parsed.name

    callback(parsed);
}

function callback(args){
    alert(JSON.stringify(args));
}


foo({name:"Peter",extra:2},callback);//yields {"name":"Peter","age":12,"extra":2}
foo({name:"Mark",age:92},callback);  //yields {"name":"Mark","age":92}
foo({},callback);                    //yields {"name":"John Doe","age":12}
```

#### Explanation

Depending on the number of arguments to pass it might look too verbose to your liking. The concept should be self explanatory but to put it in words, we group the arguments in an object and inside the function have an object with the default values (if needed). Then we override the defaults with those passed leaving us a very clear and clean `callback` and verbose args.

Note that if extra parameters are passed, those are not lost in the process of setting the defaults.